# Do get Apple Push back to working, do I need to push an iOS app update?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

> Your Apple Push Services Certificate will no longer be valid in 30
>   days. To generate a new certificate, sign in and visit Certificates,
>    Identifiers & Profiles.
>
> - Certificate: Apple Push Services
> - Identifier: com.bpl.Beam
> - Team ID: JF2FFVM7JG
>
> To learn more about expired certificates, visit the certificates
>   support page."

So, I renewed apple push notification for my app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMLCY.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKcZn.jpg).

(My app occasionally gave notification of received image without receiving/displaying the image which I am debugging, hence.)

Do I need to do iOS side update (code or app?) for Apple push to work?

(I also created a certificate and key text file [following](https://vivocha.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/VVCJ/pages/1048822/How+to+create+the+Apple+Push+Notification+Certificate+and+Key) ).

Please help/guide with step-by-step suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to put the new certificates in your backend that is in charge of send the notifications to the APNS. The app will continue to work receiving the notifications without any change needed.

Comment: but my push notification is not working now; i do not receive text.

Comment: Well I don't know where is the problem. You must check the backend if there are problems in the interaction with the APNS.

Comment: thanks, it worked on updating Apple Push certificate which had expired.